# Updating rows from Xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am attempting to update multiple rows from an Xml input from an application datalayer Originally, we would write the update stored procedure something like this:

The input Xml:

```
<root>
   <Customer CustomerId="123" LastName="Doe" FirstName="John" />
   <Customer CustomerId="124" LastName="Doe" FirstName="Jane" />
</root>
```

Stored procedure:

```
   UPDATE Customer
   SET    FirstName = xd.FirstName,
          LastName = xd.LastName
   FROM   OPENXML(@dh, '//Customer')
          WITH (CustomerId INT, LastName VARCHAR(50), FirstName VARCHAR(50)) xd
   WHERE  CustomerId = xd.CustomerId;
```

This works just fine and works for single and multiple rows, but the WITH section can get kind of crazy long on large tables or especially if there is a multiple update/insert statements in one procedure, having to repeat the same columns over and over. Also the chance of a developer getting the type or size wrong, or the type or size changing.  Next step was using the table itself as the data definition of the Xml:

```
UPDATE Customer
   SET    FirstName = xd.FirstName,
          LastName = xd.LastName
   FROM   OPENXML(@dh, '//Customer')
          WITH Customer xd
   Customer.CustomerId = @xml.value('(//Customer/@CustomerId)[1]', 'int');
```

This was much better to me.  Cleaner, easier to read, easier to maintain. For whatever reason the primary key is not included as a column, so you have to parse that out separately, which is silly to me, but it was just one column and always an int so it works fine.

Now the actual problem, what if I am updating multiple rows?  Using the singleton CustomerId obviously isn't going to work but I just can't figure out the correct syntax. I'm thinking I need some type of WHERE IN (the Xml) function, but I can't figure that out.

PS. I know this has morphed into a little bit of an odd syntax with he mixing of OPENXML and native xml functions, but I'd like to keep the OPENXML and using the table to define the structure instead of having to define each column for the reasons above.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I still think that it's not the best idea to stick with OPENXML, but here's a suggestion which might work for you:

You start your UPDATE with a CTE delivering all IDs found within your XML. At the end of your statement you do not check against one single value but with an IN-clause. As your CTE's name is "AllIDs" this bottom line is the same in all cases. The only thing you'd have to change is the CTE. And there's an even better trick maybe, see below...

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<root>
   <Customer CustomerId="123" LastName="Doe" FirstName="John" />
   <Customer CustomerId="124" LastName="Doe" FirstName="Jane" />
</root>';

WITH AllIDs AS
(
    SELECT One.Customer.value('@CustomerId','int') AS ID
    FROM @xml.nodes('/root/Customer') AS One(Customer)
)

   UPDATE Customer
   SET    FirstName = xd.FirstName,
          LastName = xd.LastName
   FROM   OPENXML(@dh, '//Customer')
          WITH (CustomerId INT, LastName VARCHAR(50), FirstName VARCHAR(50)) xd
   WHERE  CustomerId IN(SELECT ID FROM AllIDs)
```

This could make it even better: If your ID-column is always ending on "Id" you might define your CTE with this SELECT and you would not even have to type any specific line...

```
SELECT One.Item.value('(@*[fn:substring(fn:local-name(), fn:string-length(fn:local-name()) - fn:string-length("Id")+1)="Id"])[1]','int') AS ID
    FROM @xml.nodes('/root/*') AS One(Item)
```

Or, if the Id is always the parents name with an appended "Id" (Customer+Id=CustomerId) you might try

```
SELECT One.Item.value('(@*[local-name() = fn:concat(fn:local-name(..),"Id")])[1]','varchar(max)') AS ID
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/*') AS One(Item)
```

#### This is the old answer...

You want to stick to OPENXML... Why? This is out-dated and should be replaced by the "real" XML data type nowadays...

Use this to read your file:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
(
    (
    SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'YourPathToTheFile\testXml.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
    )
);

SELECT @xml;
```

Without knowing your XML's structure I cannot show you the correct Query... But believe me: This will be - for sure! - much easier than all the things you try at the moment.

Please edit your question and show us (at least part of) your XML. I'll be glad to help you to define the fitting query...

EDIT: According to your comment you have the data for your update operations coming as an XML already - even better!

With this easy Code you can Update all in one go:

I use for testing a declared table variable (`@Customer`). You just have to adapt this to your actual table's name.

```
DECLARE @Customer TABLE(CustomerId INT, FirstName VARCHAR(100), LastName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Customer VALUES(123,'John','TestJohn')
                           ,(124,'Jane','TestJane')
                           ,(125,'Another','One');

SELECT * FROM @Customer;                     

/*
CustomerId  FirstName   LastName
123          John        TestJohn
124          Jane        TestJane
125          Another     One
*/

DECLARE @xml XML=
'<root>
   <Customer CustomerId="123" LastName="Doe" FirstName="John" />
   <Customer CustomerId="124" LastName="Doe" FirstName="Jane" />
</root>';

WITH UpdateRows AS
(
    SELECT One.Customer.value('@CustomerId','int') AS CustomerId
          ,One.Customer.value('@FirstName','varchar(max)') AS FirstName
          ,One.Customer.value('@LastName','varchar(max)') AS LastName
    FROM @xml.nodes('/root/Customer') AS One(Customer)
)
UPDATE @Customer SET FirstName=ur.FirstName
                    ,LastName=ur.LastName
FROM @Customer AS c
INNER JOIN UpdateRows AS ur ON c.CustomerId=ur.CustomerId;

SELECT * FROM @Customer;                     

/*
CustomerId  FirstName   LastName
123          John        Doe
124          Jane        Doe
125          Another     One
*/
```

Comment: I already explained why I wanted to keep OPENXML: I prefer the brevity of the declaration.  I'm not locked to it though, show something better. Also, I already have an Xml datatype coming into the stored procedure, not a local file. I thought that was clear in the question, but I guess I should have explicitly stated that the data is coming from an application datalayer for a table update, not a bulk import of some kind. I also thought I made the example simple enough to 'see' the structure, but in the spirit of SO, I have edited and added the structure.

Comment: @ComputerChip, Sorry, had no time... Please see my edit section. Hope this helps. If something is not clear - just ask!

Comment: Thank you for the edit and example, but the mess of re-defining each column, type, and size in hard-coded text is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @ComputerChip I just edited my answer to give you a completely different approach. I'm very curious, if this works for your ;-)

Comment: Very interesting idea and pretty much what I was thinking in my question when I stated "I need some type of WHERE IN (the Xml) function".  Your solution has the same problem that one of mine did (not shown in the question) where every row in the table with a matching ID gets updated with the first node of data from the Xml. :(  So you end up with both 123 and 123 records as John Doe.

Comment: @ComputerChip The **only** way to update a list with a joined list, needs to have two lists to join... That's why I pointed you to the CTE-approach in the first attempt. You are right, that my last idea did not think of that... How you can do the update with joined lists you find at the bottom of my answer. How you get your lists is up to you... If you do not like the typing of the `.value()` methods, you might generate them from your target tables? If the structure is always a plain *"root and row by row with attributes"* you might query this generically...

Answer (score 0):

The column `CustomerId` is not missing because it is the primary key. It is missing because it is an identity column.

[Michael Rys [MSFT]](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/SQL-Server/microsoft.public.sqlserver.xml/2004-08/0184.html)

> This is a restriction of the OpenXML WITH clause since IDENTITY values
>   are generated automatically and we do not know, whether you want it to
>   take from  the XML document or not.

The workaround is to declare the columns in the `WITH` clause or to use the XML variable directly.

If you decide to move away from openxml it would look like this.

```sql
update Customer
set FirstName = C.FirstName,
    LastName = C.LastName
from (
     select C.X.value('@CustomerId', 'int') as CustomerId,
            C.X.value('@FirstName', 'varchar(50)') as FirstName,
            C.X.value('@LastName', 'varchar(50)') as LastName
     from @xml.nodes('/root/Customer') as C(X)
     ) as C
where Customer.CustomerId = C.CustomerID;
```

Comment: That's right, identity, not PK...forgot that :)  I know I can do it like in your example, but the mess of re-defining each column, type, and size in hard-coded text is exactly what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @ComputerChip Forgot to mention that Michael Rys is the guy at Microsoft that was responsible for designing the XML stuff in SQL Server.